# queryIntentActivities found receivers but it doesn't Starts

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an App1 which should start a set of apps App2, App3...,

I know I can specify the package name, but I prefer to send a BroadCast to start a set of Apps that I've developed, all at the same time, and without worrying about checking which of them are installed.

App1 sends checks if there are any apps to handle the intent, if so, i sends the intent.

```
Intent dispara = new Intent();
      dispara.setAction("com.ciu.SMV.dispara");
      dispara.putExtra("TimeStamp", timee);
      dispara.setType("text/plain");

      if(verificaReceptor(context,dispara))
          context.sendBroadcast(dispara);
```

App1 finds activities to handle the intent, sends the intent but App2 never starts.

```
public static boolean verificaReceptor(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final PackageManager mgr = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (D)
        Log.d(TAG, "Apps disponibles: " + list.size() + " Apps: "+list + intent);
    return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Log result:

> /com.ciumx.smv D/onTickBroadCast﹕ Apps disponibles: 1 Apps: [ResolveInfo{412ceab8 com.ciumx.notificador.NotificadorAct p=0 o=0 m=0x608000}]Intent { act=com.ciu.SMV.dispara typ=text/plain (has extras) }

The manifest in App2

```
<activity
        android:name=".NotificadorAct"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notificador" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ciu.SMV.dispara" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

The OnCreate of App2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notificador);

    log("onCreate....", "Creado");

    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            log("LALA","LLEGÓ TEXTO"); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            log("LALA","LLEGÓ imágen"); // Handle text being sent // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            log("LALA","Muchas Imágenes"); // Handle text being sent // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
    } else {
        // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen
    }

}
```

So App1 can see receptors, but App2 never starts :/, any idea?

My best regards

Comment: Targets of sendBroadcast are BroadcastRecivers not Actvities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
context.startActivity(dispara);
```

instead of

```
context.sendBroadcast(dispara);
```